# How to check if a group of files is readable?

Tags: shell-script, files, test

I have to check if a group of files is readable. I know how I would go about checking one file by using `[ -r file.txt ]`, but how would I go about writing a loop that would check multiple files (including directories)?

E.g., `file1.txt file2.txt directory1 directory2 file3.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

The following function checks that all of its arguments are readable files:

```
files_are_readable () {
  for x do
    [ -r "$x" ] || return 1
  done
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In bash you could do

```
for file in file1.txt file2.txt directory1; do
    if [[ -r $file ]]; then
        ...
    fi
done
```

and the part that is the list of files can be anything where you can read each "word" separated by space and put it in $file, so you could, say

```
for file in $(find .); do
    ...
done
```

if you want to do something to all the files and directories under your current directory or anything else like that.  Be careful with the example with find though, if you have spaces in any of your file or directory names $file will still be splitting on space so it would get each part as a different "file" to try